# aws serve a file through s3 serverless

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to serve an audio file from S3 using a lambda function in python.

My lambda function is producing an `Internal server error` message, with the CloudWatch log showing:

`23:42:07   An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: b'\xff\xfb\x90\xc4\x00\x00\...`

Below is the code in my python lambda function

```
import boto3

def getAudio(event, context):
    #[Validate permissions here]
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    my_bucket = 'my-app'
    my_key = "audio/%s.mp3"%(event['pathParameters']['audio_id'])
    s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=my_key)
    return s3_object['Body'].read()
```

What is the appropriate way to retrieve and pass the audio file?

My endpoint is `https://1cbbkp15ci.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/assert/audio/adfk-m1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleanest way to create a Signed URL for S3 and redirect to that URL.

> Lambda (Validate Permissions and Create Signed URL) --> Redirect (302)
>   --> Actual file in S3 bucket

**Python Signed URL Generation Code:**

```
import boto3
import requests

# Get the service client.
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    }
)

# Use the URL to perform the GET operation. You can use any method you like
# to send the GET, but we will use requests here to keep things simple.
response = requests.get(url)
```

Additionally, if you want the serve with right content type. Set the content type of the object in S3. You can set with command line or even with boto3 as well.

> aws s3api put-object --bucket bucket --key foo.mp3 --body foo.mp3
>   --content-type audio/mpeg

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Using this and tweaking the "ExpiresIn" parameter was just what I needed.

Comment: Glad to see it helped.